# Search listview but instead of filtering, just inflate and display the valid items

Tags: java, android, image, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a arraylist of buttons (**reserveButtons**) that I can display in a listview. I have made a search function which searches in my database and outputs a list of integers (**resultID**). They correspond to the indexes of ***reserveButtons*** I want to display.

Simply put, I want to do something like this when the search button is clicked:

```
ArrayAdapter<ReserveButton> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
ListView list = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.resultslist);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

for (int result : resultID) {
    adapter.add(reserveButtons.get(result));
}
```

So, for each result, I want to add the corresponding button to the listview.

Here is the private class **MylistAadapter** :

```
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReserveButton> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, reserveButtons);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null) {
            itemView = gettActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
            ReserveButton currentButton = reserveButtons.get(position);

            //the resultItem is the id of the buttons
            Button butt = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultItem);

            butt.setBackground(currentButton.getImage());

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

I know that **getView** will just display every **reserveButton**, but I want the code in **getView** to be executed when I add each button, but the position doesn't change since **position** = **result** in the for loop of the first code block.

```
    //This code is inside MyListAdapter
    @Override
    public void add(ReserveButton object) {

        /* What do I write here to inflate a list_item and give it
        the background image reserveButton.get(result).getImage() */

        super.add(object);
    }
```

How do I override the **add** method of **MyListAdapter** so that I can add a **reserveButton** and change its background image for each result in the **resultID** list.

If the same thing can be accomplished without the **add** method, please do tell.

P.S: I do not want to just list every **reserveButton** and then filter them with the search; I want to display ONLY the buttons that the user is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself!

Basically, what I did was create a separate ArrayList of **ReserveButtons** and do the foreach loop like so:

```
        int index = 0;
        for (int result : resultID) {
            //result is the single ID of an answer
            answerButtons.add(index,reserveButtons.get(result));
            index ++;
        }
        populateListView();
```

So I end up storing ONLY the buttons I want to display in the **answerButtons** list. And here is what happens in populateListView()

```
    private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<ReserveButton> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.resultslist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

and the getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null) {
            itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        //Just set the image of the corresponding answerButton
        ReserveButton currentButton = answerButtons.get(position);
        Button butt = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resultItem);
        butt.setBackground(currentButton.getImage());
        return itemView;
    }
```

Problem solved. I haven't seen any answers to a problem like this, so this post should make it easily google-able for any newcomer who stumbles upon this problem.